# Angularjs: accessing scope variable array and calculating average

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, average

sorry if the question is a little abstract from the title. I will try to explain it here and supply a Gist with relevant code.

I have a JSON api which I grab through AngularJS. This is basically a project which has several tasks. I want to go through the tasks in my $scope.projects variable (in my projects controller) and get all the 'progress' values in each task. Then I want calculate the average of them to give the overall progress for the project itself and assign it to a $scope variable to be used in my template.

I cant seem to get access to the tasks array no matter what I try and I have no idea why. So i thought asking here for some advice might be a good option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Tasemu/8002741

**JS**

```
App.controller('ProjectCtrl', ['$scope', 'Project', 'Task', '$routeParams', '$location', function($scope, Project, Task, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.updateProjects = function() {
        if (!$routeParams.id) {
            Project.query(function(data) {
            $scope.projects = data;
            });
        } else {
            $scope.projects = Project.get({id: $routeParams.id})
        }
    };

    $scope.deleteProject = function(project) {
        Project.delete({id: project.id}, function() {
            $scope.updateProjects({id: project.id});
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };

    $scope.deleteTask = function(task) {
        Task.delete({id: task.id}, function() {
            $scope.updateProjects({id: task.id});
        });
    };

    $scope.updateProject = function(formData) {
        $scope.projects.name = formData.name;
        $scope.projects.description = formData.description;
        $scope.projects.client = formData.client;
        $scope.projects.due = formData.due;
        $scope.projects.$update({id: formData.id}, function() {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };

    $scope.saveProject = function(project) {
        Project.save({}, project, function() {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };

    $scope.updateProjects();

    $scope.progs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i > $scope.projects.tasks.length; i++) {
    progs.push($scope.projects.tasks.array[i].progress);
    };

    }]);
```

**JSON**

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Project 1",
  description: "this project",
  client: "monty",
  due: "2013-12-15",
  tasks: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Task 2",
      progress: 22,
      project_id: 1,
      created_at: "2013-12-17T03:08:53.849Z",
      updated_at: "2013-12-17T05:06:31.602Z"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Task 1",
      progress: 75,
      project_id: 1,
      created_at: "2013-12-17T03:08:53.845Z",
      updated_at: "2013-12-17T05:25:50.405Z"
    }
  ],
  created_at: "2013-12-17T03:08:53.719Z",
  updated_at: "2013-12-17T06:57:52.699Z"
}
```

**JS**

```
App.factory('Project', function($resource) {
return $resource(
    '/api/v1/projects/:id.json',
    {id: '@id'},
    {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
            params: { id: '@id' },
            isArray: false
        }
    }
);
});
```

If you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Where is the source code for Project.query()? is it using $http?

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Comment: Where is the code to calculate average?

Comment: Hi, I will update the Gist now with my query code. I am using $resource for it.

Comment: I have not included my code trying to access it because I was pretty much walking around blind anyway. I tried looping through them with a for loop, and pushing the 'progress' values to a new array. It just returned a 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' error in the console. I will update the Gist now with my loop also. Thanks guys!

Comment: If `Project.query()` is returning the JSON, then `data.tasks` should have the tasks array.

Comment: I thought the same thing ranru, However unless I'm doing my for loop wrong (which wouldn't surprise me) then I'm not sure why I am getting the error specified in my comment. :/

Comment: Apparently my $scope.projects.tasks is undefined, which has me stumped since I am calling it in various places with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delay the progress calculation (line 46 to 48 in `project_controller.js`) until your data is fully loaded. Extract the calculation into a new method and call this new method in the callback on line 6 and in a new callback you have to create at line 9.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `project.tasks` before it is ready. I suggest you wrap the calculation in a function and call it in the success callback when retrieving/updating projects.

```
$scope.updateProjects = function() {
    if (!$routeParams.id) {
      Project.query(function(data) {
        $scope.projects = data;
        $scope.calculateTasks();
      });
    } else {
        $scope.projects = Project.get({id: $routeParams.id})
    }
};

...
$scope.calculateTasks = function () {
    $scope.progs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i > $scope.projects.tasks.length; i++) {
        $scope.progs.push($scope.projects.tasks.array[i].progress);
    };
}
$scope.updateProjects();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. I almost got it from this, I just had to add another callback. Thanks again. :)